# Unable to Read Sample BRISQUE SVM Model YAML for OpenCV 4.5.5

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-quality

I intend to use OpenCV BRISQUE quality metric for reference-less image quality evaluation. For now, I am simply trying to use [pre-trained BRISQUE model](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/quality/samples/brisque_model_live.yml) and [range](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/quality/samples/brisque_range_live.yml) files provided with OpenCV to get a feel of the feature. Here is my code for the same:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>
#include <opencv2/quality.hpp>

int main()
{
    string brisqueModel = "brisque_model_live.yml",
           brisqueRange = "brisque_range_live.yml";

    // Invoked for debugging.
    const auto temp = cv::ml::SVM::load(brisqueModel); // Called internally by the QualityBRISQUE Constructor. Throws an exception here.

    // My intended use.
    // const auto brisqueObj = cv::quality::QualityBRISQUE::create(brisqueModel, brisqueRange);
    
    return 0;
}
```

OpenCV throws the following run-time exception for the above code:

> OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
> OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: Parsing error (Missing or invalid SVM type) in cv::ml::SVMImpl::read_params, file D:\Work\Softwares\opencv-4.5.5\opencv-4.5.5\modules\ml\src\svm.cpp, line 2206

Exception is pointing toward an invalid SVM model type. Following is the exact line in OpenCV source from where the exception is being generated:
[image: Call Stack]

However, as per the model file, [brisque_model_live.yml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/quality/samples/brisque_model_live.yml), the *svmType* name seems valid:
[image: OpenCV Pre-trained Model]

Any help to understand such a behaviour is highly appreciated.

Comment: hmm, `ml::SVM::load(brisqueModel);` returns a valid instance here (4.5.5-dev). can you set a breakpoint at 2205 and debug it ? look into `svm_type_str` ?